# Why should I have my GPG key expire?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-infrastructure, gnupg

When creating a key pair using `gpg` it asks me for an expiration date:

$ gpg --gen-key

```
Please specify how long the key should be valid.
         0 = key does not expire
      <n>  = key expires in n days
      <n>w = key expires in n weeks
      <n>m = key expires in n months
      <n>y = key expires in n years
```

Why is this needed and what are the advantages of having an expiration date?

Answer (score 3):

If your private key ever leaked then at least the damage would be time limited.

https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/c481.html

Comment: No, this is **plain wrong**. See my answer to http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14718/does-gpg-key-expiration-add-to-security/79386#79386 (where the top-voted answer is plain wrong, again).

Comment: @JensErat Sure you could extend the expiry but that's open to detection, especially when there's an alternative replacement with new keys (assuming you generate new keys) knocking about. In addition if you do change the keys on expiry then the old keys are useless for eavesdropping, only good for impersonation.

Comment: Why trust in somebody to realize a changed expiration date (nobody will), when you could simply revoke your key instead (people will realize, as their client software tells them)? Switching subkeys is a completely unrelated matter.