# how to update GPG private key that Pass uses

Tags: password-management, gnupg

I've setup up [Pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) with a GPG key. That key expires at some point in the future. In preparation for this event, how would I update Pass to use a new Key? Do I just manually update the key id and password file that Pass uses?

Comment: the man page describes ~/.password-store/.gpg-id have you tried looking in there for clues? I don't know this utility, never used it. but that's where i would start.

Comment: yeah that was my first stop, it's not clear to me how to update the key.

Comment: nvm it was in the man page all along.

Comment: glad you got it sorted :) hah, yeah its in the text for the first item, looked over it the first time cuz i thought it was only for initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking closer at the man page you can update the public encryption key with:

```
pass init [ --path=sub-folder, -p sub-folder ] new-gpg-id
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can simply extend the key's validity period by running `gpg --edit-key <key-id>`. Anyway, [key expiry dates don't really add additional security](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/14718/19837).